# TYPO3 10 & tx_news Version 9.0.0 Pagination of category news lists

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I updated news extension to version 9.0.0. Since the `ViewHelper <n:widget.paginate>` is no longer supported, I have changed the pagination related lines of list template to render the pagination partial as recommended. In the template pagination.html e.g. the next button gets created with following link:

`href="{f:uri.action(action:actionName, arguments:{currentPage: pagination.nextPageNumber})}"`

This works fine for the list of all news. Means without any category filter.

Problem is for category lists of news.
If the first block of news of selected category gets displayed, the URL shows:
`"https://xyz.de/news/category1"`

The pagination button 'next' does not point to the next page of the list of category news. It points to the next page of the complete list of all news ignoring the category filter:
`"https://xyz.de/news/page-2"`

The expected link would be:
`"https://xyz.de/news/category1/page-2"`

Is there anything I can do to get the correct pagination links?

Thanks and best regards
Wulf

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the argument `addQueryString:1` in the partial.

This has been fixed in EXT:news with the commit
https://github.com/georgringer/news/commit/9297aa5602e167273e53910c0db81bb6fe102a9a

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. Without using routenhancer category-name this is working fine. However if routepath category-name will be used, the query argument overwriteDemand/categories is again not part of the paginator links anymore. Could this be an issue of routenhancer script or could it be an issue of Pagination partial?

Comment: I created a new issue https://github.com/georgringer/news/issues/1640 and will check it out in the next days

Comment: can you please share your config in the issue? thanks a lot

Comment: My news related part ot the routenhancer is shared on https://github.com/georgringer/news/issues/1640